# Why does Django wrap INSERT and DELETE statements in BEGIN/COMMIT?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, autocommit

I've found from the docs that Django uses [autocommit](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#why-django-uses-autocommit) by default when talking to the database. I haven't changed this setting. However, in the db query log I can see that it still wraps each `INSERT` or `DELETE` in `BEGIN`/`COMMIT`, while `SELECTS` are not being wrapped. I wonder why is this necessary? Any links to the docs would be appreciated.